# Express a permutation as the product of two involutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

> Let $\alpha = (1\ 2\ 4\ 5\ 6) (23\ 24\ 26\ 7\ 9) (3) (17) (13\ 20\ 21\ 8\ 22\ 19\ 25) (9\ 11\ 12\ 14\ 15\ 16\ 10)$ be a permutation.
>
> Express the permutation as a product of two involutions without fixed elements in two different ways

I have computed that $\alpha = (9\ 11\ 12\ 14\ 15\ 16\ 10\ 23\ 24\ 26\ 7)(13\ 20\ 21\ 8\ 22\ 19\ 25) (1\ 2\ 4\ 5\ 6)(3)(17)(18)$. Hence, the cycle type of $\alpha$ is $(11,7,5,1,1,1)$.

We know that if two permutations $\beta$ and $\delta$ are involutions without fixed elements, then each number of the cycle type of $\beta \delta$ appears an even number of times.

Since in the type of $\alpha$ no number appears an even number of times, that means we cannot express $\alpha$ as a product of two involutions without fixed elements? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The permutation $(1\ 2)(2\  3)$ equals $(1\ 2\ 3)$, which has cycle type $(3)$, where the number $3$ appears an odd number of times in the cycle type. I'm not sure what you mean by an “involution without fixed elements,” however.

Comment: @SteveKass Thaks for your comment, "without fixed elements" means that each element has to go to another different. For example, in the permutation $(1\ 2\ 4)$, $3$ is fixed. I know that we can express each cycle as product of traspositions, but is it useful for the question?

Comment: Is the definition of $\alpha$ correct?  What does the "a" at the ned of the first line mean?  Also, I notice that $18$ never appears explicitly, although you have $(3)$ and $(17)$ and that $9$ is the only number that appears twice.

Comment: @saulspatz The "a" is from let $\alpha$ be "a" permutation, I have edited the question for more clearly. I have copied $\alpha$ as it is in my notes. I have noticed that $18$ never appears explicitly while $3$ and $17$ do, but I think that is because we have to know that every cycle of leght $1$ is the identity. And I think that $9$ apperas twice because in first place we have to compute the permutation as disjoint cycles.

Comment: I think there is a mistake, and there should be two cycles of length 7, two of length 5, and two fixed points, with all cycles disjoint. Then it would be possible. (You have not really explained why they would mention two of the fixed points and not the third.)

Comment: I agree with others that it looks like a typo. As saulspatz noticed, 9 appears twice and 18 is missing. Maybe one of the 9s was supposed to be the number 18.

Comment: Maybe it will be as Derek Holt and Steve Kass say. It has to be a typo. If we consider one of the $9$s as $18$, we have a permutation with type $(7,7,5,5,1,1)$. Then as each number appears twice at the type, we can express the permutation as the product of two involutions without fixed elements.